# Google Maps e WebSocket Flutter

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, flutter, dart

Bom, vamos lá...
Estou desenvolvento uma aplicação utilizando flutter (sou novato com a lingua dart), então preciso que minha aplicação atualize os markers do maps periodicamente junto com o WebSocket, porem quando o mesmo atualiza meu maps para de funcionar, deixando assim a tela toda branca...

```
@override

void initState() {
    super.initState();
    checkUserLogged();
    _getAddrs();
    wsConnect();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    channel.sink.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  wsConnect() async {
    channel = await IOWebSocketChannel.connect('ws://31.220.54.205:3002');
    channel.stream.listen((message) {
      channel.sink.add(message);
    });
  }




StreamBuilder(
                stream: channel.stream,
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    var jsonResult = json.decode(snapshot.data);

                    for (var end in jsonResult) {
                      _markers.add(
                        Marker(
                          markerId: MarkerId((end['truck_name'].length > 0 ? end['truck_name'] : 'Caminhão de Lixo')),
                          draggable: false,
                          icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromAsset("assets/pngs/caminhaozinho.png"),
                          position: LatLng(double.parse(end['truck_lat']), double.parse(end['truck_lng'])),
                        ),
                      );
                    }

                    return Container(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      child: GoogleMap(
                        myLocationEnabled: true,
                        myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
                        minMaxZoomPreference: MinMaxZoomPreference(14, 17),
                        onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
                        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                          target: LatLng(lat, long),
                          zoom: 17.0,
                        ),
                        compassEnabled: true,
                        markers: Set.from(_markers),
                      ),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return MaterialApp(
                      home: Scaffold(
                        body: Container(
                          child: Center(
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.green
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                }
              ),
```

Quando eu rodo a aplicação no meu emulador eu recebo o seguinte log:

> I/flutter ( 6163): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>   I/flutter ( 6163): The following StateError was thrown building MediaQuery(MediaQueryData(size: Size(411.4, 683.4),
>   I/flutter ( 6163): devicePixelRatio: 2.6, textScaleFactor: 1.0, platformBrightness: Brightness.light, padding:
>   I/flutter ( 6163): EdgeInsets(0.0, 24.0, 0.0, 0.0), viewPadding: EdgeInsets(0.0, 24.0, 0.0, 0.0), viewInsets:
>   I/flutter ( 6163): EdgeInsets.zero, alwaysUse24HourFormat: false, accessibleNavigation: false, disableAnimations:
>   I/flutter ( 6163): false, invertColors: false, boldText: false)):
>   I/flutter ( 6163): Bad state: Stream has already been listened to.
>   I/flutter ( 6163):
>   I/flutter ( 6163): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #3      _CompleterStream.listen (package:async/src/stream_completer.dart:133:31)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #7      _StreamBuilderBaseState._subscribe (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:135:37)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #8      _StreamBuilderBaseState.initState (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:109:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #9      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4033:58)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #10     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3902:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #11     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #12     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5198:32)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #13     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #14     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #15     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #16     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #17     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3907:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #18     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3902:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #19     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #20     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #21     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #22     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #23     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3907:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #24     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3902:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #25     ParentDataElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4279:11)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #26     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #27     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5198:32)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #28     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #29     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #30     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #31     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #32     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3907:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #33     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4053:11)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #34     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3902:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #35     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #36     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #37     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #38     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #39     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3907:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #40     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3902:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #41     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #42     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #43     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #44     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #45     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3907:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #46     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4053:11)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #47     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3902:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #48     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #49     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #50     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5092:14)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #51     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #52     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #53     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #54     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #55     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3907:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #56     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3902:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #57     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #58     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #59     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5092:14)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #60     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #61     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #62     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #63     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #64     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3907:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #65     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4053:11)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #66     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3902:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #67     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #68     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #69     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #70     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #71     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3907:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #72     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4053:11)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #73     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3902:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #74     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #75     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #76     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #77     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #78     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3907:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #79     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3902:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #80     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #81     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #82     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #83     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #84     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3907:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #85     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3902:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #86     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #87     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #88     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #89     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #90     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3907:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #91     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4053:11)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #92     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3902:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #93     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #94     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #95     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5099:14)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #96     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #97     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #98     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #99     StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3981:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #100    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #101    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5099:14)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #102    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #103    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5099:14)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #104    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #105    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5099:14)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #106    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #107    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5099:14)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #108    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #109    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #110    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #111    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4085:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #112    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #113    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #114    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #115    StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3981:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #116    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #117    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #118    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #119    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4085:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #120    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #121    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5099:14)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #122    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #123    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #124    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #125    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4219:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #126    _InheritedNotifierElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/inherited_notifier.dart:94:11)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #127    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #128    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5099:14)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #129    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #130    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #131    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #132    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4085:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #133    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #134    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #135    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #136    StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3981:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #137    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #138    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5099:14)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #139    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #140    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #141    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #142    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4219:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #143    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #144    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
>   E/eglCodecCommon( 6163): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008741
>   E/eglCodecCommon( 6163): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008741
>   E/eglCodecCommon( 6163): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008741
>   E/eglCodecCommon( 6163): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008741
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #145    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #146    BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2340:33)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #147    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:700:20)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #148    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:285:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #149    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1016:15)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #150    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:958:9)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #151    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:874:5)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #155    _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:236:10)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): #156    _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:194:3)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): (elided 9 frames from package dart:async)
>   I/flutter ( 6163): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>   I/flutter ( 6163): Another exception was thrown: The _ScaffoldLayout custom multichild layout delegate forgot to lay out the following child:
>   I/flutter ( 6163): Another exception was thrown: Bad state: Stream has already been listened to.
>   I/flutter ( 6163): Another exception was thrown: The _ScaffoldLayout custom multichild layout delegate forgot to lay out the following children:
>   Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...             7.306ms (!)

Alguém saberia como me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Imagens do emulador do estado da tela são importantes !!!

Problema esta na interface, esta dando `media.query` error e `overflow`, por isso o motivo da tela estar branca (como você descreveu).

Tente rever sua interface e as medidas dela

Se o problema estiver nos pacotes

```
flutter clean
flutter run
```